# Rotating clock hands in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, clock

I am trying to create a clock using jQuery. I am able to rotate all the hours, minutes and seconds hands, but am having some problems in rotating it exactly in Internet Explorer as it does in other browsers.

Why is this occurring? How can I rotate the clock hands in Internet Explorer as in other browsers?

This is what I have created so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var every_second = 1000;
    var every_minute = 60000;
    var every_twelve_minute = 60000;

    setInterval(rotateSeconds,every_second);
    setInterval(rotateMinutes,every_minute);
    setInterval(rotateHours,every_twelve_minute);
});

var seconds_angle = 0;
function rotateSeconds() {
    var element = $(".seconds");
    if(seconds_angle < 360) {
        seconds_angle = seconds_angle+5;
    }
    else {
        seconds_angle = 0;
    }
    element.rotate(seconds_angle);
}

var minutes_angle = 0;
function rotateMinutes() {
    var element = $(".minutes");
    if(minutes_angle < 360) {
        minutes_angle = minutes_angle+5;
    }
    else {
        minutes_angle = 0;
    }
    element.rotate(minutes_angle);
}

var hours_angle = 0;
function rotateHours() {
    var element = $(".hours");
    if(hours_angle < 360) {
        hours_angle = hours_angle+1.25;
    }
    else {
        hours_angle = 0;
    }
    element.rotate(hours_angle);
}
```

and here's a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LYzzX/1/) to everything

Comment: I have moved your code into your question. Please _always_ do this. A jsFiddle link is helpful but you should always put the code in the question. Secondly, please do _not_ randomly highlight words. You did not have any code in your question so don't mark anything up as code. jQuery is fine.... rather than `jQuery` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't say what is wrong precisely with your clock in IE -- and in which version of IE.

If I were do draw an analog clock on a web page I would probably go with SVG.

IE6-8 has no support for SVG so if you need to support that I would use the [Raphaël JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) library. It creates SVG where available and falls back to proprietary VML on IE6-8. Look at their web site they have cool examples, including a funny polar clock (the concentric circles).

Here's an article explaining exactly what you try to achieve: an analog clock done on top of Raphael: [Analog clock without images](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/12/11/javascript-analog-clock-with-no-images-and-no-css/), complete with a frame and hour tick marks.

Answer (score 12):

You have two choices :

- you can run to a jQuery plugin which handle cross browser rotations and you will easily find one in google.
- OR, you may get interested in microsoft matrix transforms : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(v=vs.85).aspx , and you will have to learn what is a 2*2 rotation matrix and how its terms have to be computed. That's not complicated. The difference with css3 rotation is that the rotation center is by default the top left corner of your element and you may have to work with margins.

So if you choose the second solution : for IE 9 and 10, use -ms-transform rule with css3 rotate function, and for others IE, use filter rule with Microsoft matrices.
You may use Modernizr to detect csstransforms feature and use the css parent condition with the css classes .csstranforms and .no-csstransformsMdernizr added onload.

Answer (score 6):

IE 8,7,... doesn't support CSS rotation

Comment: Isn't there any other way of rotating it?

Comment: Somewhat look at that article: http://www.aquim.com/web-article-226.html . Search Google for `rotation on IE8` there are some frameworks that might support it

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [jQuery Rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) that will handle the cross-browser for you, and you just need to rotate using this:

```
$('#myImage').rotate(30) //for a 30 degree rotation Where #myImage is the id of the element you want rotated.
```

It is supported by the following browsers:

- Internet Explorer 6.0 >
- Firefox 2.0 >
- Safari 3 >
- Opera 9 >
- Google Chrome

[Check it here.](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

Comment: Thanks. I will check it and will let you know.

Comment: Surely I will let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `canvas` element for rotating the clock hands, and it will work in IE7+8 if you include [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/), a plugin that enables canvas in old versions of IE.

IE 9 and 10 already have support for canvas.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/qVqUb/4/ (using [coolclock](http://randomibis.com/coolclock/) plugin).
Just make sure excanvas only loads if IE<9 with [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

You can use the coolclock plugin or program your own clock.

The jsfiddle website itself does not work in IE 7/8. Copy the following code in a html file and open that in IE and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' 
    src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script> 
  <script type='text/javascript' 
    src="http://randomibis.com/coolclock/coolclock.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function(){
    CoolClock.config.skins = {skin1:{
    outerBorder:
      {lineWidth:2, radius:95, color:"black", alpha:1 },
    smallIndicator:
      {lineWidth:2, startAt:88, endAt:92,color:"black", alpha:1 },
    largeIndicator:
      {lineWidth:4, startAt:79, endAt:92, color:"black", alpha:1 },
    hourHand:
      {lineWidth:8, startAt:-15,endAt:50, color:"black", alpha:1 },
    minuteHand:
      {lineWidth:7, startAt:-15, endAt:75, color:"black", alpha:1 },
    secondHand:
      {lineWidth:1, startAt:-20, endAt:85, color:"red", alpha:1 },
    secondDecoration:
      {lineWidth:1,startAt:70,radius:4,fillColor:"red",color:"red",alpha:1 }
}};
CoolClock.findAndCreateClocks();
});
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://randomibis.com/coolclock/excanvas.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="clockid" class="CoolClock:skin1:200:false">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check it and will let you know.

Comment: Hey, I checked it. It is working in Internet explorer 7 but not in Internet explorer 8. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Adding a window load event fixed it in IE8.      `window.load=function(){CoolClock.findAndCreateClocks();}` or jQuery: `$(function(){CoolClock.findAndCreateClocks();});`

Comment: It is working in Internet explorer 7 but not in Internet explorer 8

Comment: Hey. I just checked it in IE8 and it's not working. What is the problem man. Is it working for you. Can you upload your working page in IE8 somewhere and provide me a link, so i can check it and see what's the problem in my code?

Comment: See my just added link in my answer, that page does work in IE8 on 2 separate machines here. It does not work in IEtester! (a program simulating different IE versions)

Comment: Hey @willem, it's not working on my 2 machines on IE8. It does work in IE7, and it also doesn't work properly in IE9. I m sorry to say this but it's not working for me. I don't understand why.

Comment: Only last 24 hours remaining in the bounty. Can you do the final help?

Comment: Well, I can't find why it's not working in your IE8, and that will be very difficult to do when it's working over here! I did find one possible problem: 'default' is a reserved word in javascript, so try and rename the skin to 'skin1' or something.

Comment: I m not using the default keyword, i have already renamed it to something else. Well anyways thanks for your help. Let me upload my page somewhere and you can check it.

Comment: That clock does not work in my IE8 unless I put it in compatibility mode. I tested a clock built from scratch, but it still has some problems in ie8: http://jsfiddle.net/w1ll3m/7RfLs/6/ (comp. mode works though)

Comment: So is there any difference between your working clock code and my non working clock code?

Comment: Not that I can see, maybe it has something to do with the server where the page is hosted or the character encoding of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jquery transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin to make any type of transition effect including rotation . It is a light weight plugin with much options.
To change the center of rotation . You can use transformOrigin as shon below.

```
$('.box')
  .css({ transformOrigin: '0px 0px' })
  .transition({ rotate: '45deg' });
```